# When using <a href="myapp://"> to launch an iOS app from browser can you force a restart?

Tags: ios

Is there something I can add to my  that when click will not only launch my iOS app, but force the app to be restarted?

Answer (score 1):

There is not, you'll need to do the necessary [re]initialization of your app in the app delegates handleOpenURL method.